# Get Xpath for a node

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I've got 2 XML files and am merging nodes from one into the other and in one corner case I need to add a node, which requires me to actually `Clone()`. But I don't know the base XML parent objects's XPath at that point. Is there an equivalent to

```bsh
$somenode.GetXpath()
```

To allow me to

```bsh
$newNode = $file2_someNode.Clone()
$xPath = $somenode.GetTHePathtoTheNodeSomehow()
$file1.InsertAfter($NewNode, SelectSingleNode($xpath))
```

Or something to that effect?

Comment: Why not just `$file1.InsertAfter($NewNode, $somenode)`?

Comment: You don't necessarily need the full path to the node, but you need some criteria by which to select the node.